# flutter NestedScrollView with Pageview in the body not working as expected

Tags: flutter, nestedscrollview, flutter-pageview

I created a screen with nestedscrollview that consist of a sliverappbar to hide when scroll and body with pageview. but when i switching between pages with swipes the scroll is not behaving as expected. the sliver app bar not expanding when swiping forward and its working fine when swiping backward to previous pages in pageview. Is there any way to force scroll from top on every page view?